# Common methods implementation from multiple Interfaces

Tags: java, oop

I'm practicing a few project implementations on my own. Please help me with the below query:
I have 3 interfaces in which `AccountModificationAPI` is parent and `LibrarianAccountModificationAPI`, `MemberAccountModificationAPI` extends from this interface. I have a common implementation for all the common methods from `AccountModificationAPI` in both child interfaces. How can I provide a common implementation for both the child interfaces?

I tried adding an abstract class but it is asking for implementation for both the interfaces as below. Please suggest

```java
public interface AccountModificationAPI {

    int createAccount(Account account);

    Account viewAccount(String id);

    String resetPassword(String id, String password);

    String updateName(String name);

    String updatePhone(String phoneNumber);

    String updateAddress(Address address);

    String closeAccount(String accountName);

}
```

```java
public interface LibrarianAccountModificationAPI extends AccountModificationAPI {

    String resetMemberPassword(String accountName);

    Account registerMemberAccount(Account account);

    String deleteMemberAccount(String accountName);

    String updateMemberAccountStatus(String accountName);
    
    String blockMember(String accountName);

}
```

```java
public interface MemberAccountModificationAPI extends AccountModificationAPI {

    void extendAccountValidity();

}
```

```java
public abstract class AccountModificationImpl implements LibrarianAccountModificationAPI, MemberAccountModificationAPI{


        @Override
        public String resetPassword(String id, String password) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String updateName(String name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String updatePhone(String phoneNumber) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String updateAddress(Address address) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String closeAccount(String accountName) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public int createAccount(Account account) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Account viewAccount(String id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
}
```

Comment: One possible way is to create a new class that implements AccountModificationAPI and use composition way

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. And this statement is wrong _I have common implementation [...]_.  Your implementations are in `AccountModificationImpl`. That call still needs implementations for the other interfaces as well.

Comment: Sorry for that, let me rephrase it. methods from AccountModificationAPI interface has same implementation for LibrarianAccountModificationAPI and MemberAccountModificationAPI. To avoid the duplicate code for both the methods, is there anyway to have same implementation for them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the implementation of the methods from `AccountModificationAPI` in the `AccountModificationImpl`. Let us rename this class as `AbstractAccountModificationAPI`.

Now, all the implementations of `LibrarianAccountModificationAPI` and `MemberAccountModificationAPI` *extends* `AbstractAccountModificationAPI`.

This has to be done by the implementor's choice and cannot be forced upon. In other words, I could create an implementation without inheriting from `AbstractAccountModificationAPI`.

---

You can see this in JDK collection library as well. A `List` (interface) is a `Collection` (interface) and there is `AbstractCollection` abstract class. Its javadoc says

> This class provides a skeletal implementation of the Collection interface, to minimize the effort required to implement this interface.

Similarly, there is `AbstractList` (extends `AbstractCollection`) which provide a a skeletal implementation of the List interface.

Concrete class, `ArrayList` extends `AbstractList`.

On the other hand, you have to be aware of the downsides of inheritance here. The implementations cannot extend any other class.

Comment: Thank you, this really explains the con of this implementation which I never thought of...